# No connection adapters with requests module python

Tags: python, python-requests

So I have this piece of code right here:

```
import requests
url = "https://account-public-service-prod03.ol.epicgames.com/account/api/oauth/token",
headers = {
'Authorization': 'basic MzRhMDJjZjhmNDQxNGUyOWIxNTkyMTg3NmRhMzZmOWE6ZGFhZmJjY2M3Mzc3NDUwMzlkZmZlNTNkOTRmYzc2Y2Y=',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
data = {
'grant_type': "password",
'username': user,
'password': password,
'includePerms': 'true',
}
data = requests.post(url=url,data=data,headers=headers)
```

and whenever I make a post request to this website, this error pops up:

```
File "/Users/tahirakhan/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 730, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "('https://account-public-service-prod03.ol.epicgames.com/account/api/oauth/token',)"
```

can someone please help?

Comment: Remove the `,` after your url. This is causing it to be a tuple.

Comment: omg you were right. Thanks a lot!